# IBM WebSphere MQ creating scripts

Tags: ibm-mq

We have a machine with multiple MQ clusters and listeners defined. Is there any script which can be used to create an exact replica on another machine. Are there any commands/tools available?

Our platform is Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backing up a QMgr to restore else where entails the following:

- Back up object definitions. WMQ v7.1 has the `dmpmqcfg` command for this.  Prior versions use [SupportPac MS03](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMS03), a.k.a `saveqmgr`.
- Back up authorizations. Same options as previous bullet.
- Back up the .ini files
- Back up any exits and their parameter files

Note that the best practice is to restore these objects into a QMgr with a *different* name.  There are issues in trying to keep the QMgr name identical, especially if you have clusters or use a commercial certificate authority to sign SSL certs.

The index of SupportPacs [is here](http://ibm.co/SupptPacs).  There are many which can help with scripting and deployment but MS03 is my personal favorite for this task.